# Difference between Arm/Amd/aarch/armf?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, computer-architecture

I would like to know what is the main diffrence between these many architectures available for diffrent OS.

```
Amd64 /Amd32

Arm64 /Arm32

aarch64/ aarch32

armhf64/armhf32
```

I was trying to install Ubuntu on my raspberry Pi & when I search supportable architecture. all these names came out & confused what to install for my requiremnt.

### Edit 1

I've

```
raspberry Pi model - 4b 
8Gb ram version.
```

The only issue is every version installs fine but I ending up Ubuntu not supporting my raspberry Pi onboard camera which I attach though strip -[camera i was using](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/camera-module-v2/)

Comment: Is [this useful](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)?  The 32 and 64 refer to 64 bit or 32 bit versions. They are different set. It may depend from which specific hardware you have (raspberry Pi model). E.g. for debian you can read [here](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi). Welcome on SE, please [edit] your post and add this info.

Comment: @Hastur Hi, Yes, I've tried & installed both 32/64 bit from official site that you [mentioned above](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) ...All the versions I've tried failing to detect the Raspberry Pi camera attached on on-board through strip.

Comment: ...but that is another problem `:-)` good for another question (where you have to state the model of camera and the version of the installed system).  It may be useful (`dmesg | grep -i "Camera"`)

Comment: @Hastur this is the first thing I've tried `dmesg | grep -i "Camera` and also `start_x=1 ` on `onfiguration` but, still ending up camera issues

Comment: Sorry to repeat, post another question with system version, hardware specifications (camera model included), attempt made and you will probably have the help you need. Ps> Also check if it is plugged in properly (if it's not built in), sometimes we struggle to look for a software problem when there isn't one. Good Luck.

Comment: Yeah ok @Hastur Just want to know & curiose about diffrent architecture flavours so posted it..

Answer (score 8):

| Architecture | 32-bit | 64-bit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Intel x86 (PCs) | x86, i386, i486 … i686 | x86_64, amd64 |
| ARM (mobile devices) | armhf, armv7h | arm64, aarch64 |

"aarch64" and "arm64" are the same thing. AArch64 is the official name for the 64-bit ARM architecture, but some people prefer to call it "ARM64" as a continuation of 32-bit ARM.

On the other hand, all 32-bit versions of ARM were called "arm"-something (there is no such thing as "aarch32"). See [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790029/what-is-difference-between-arm64-and-armhf) and [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87392/pi1-armv6-how-to-disable-armhf-packages) about the meaning of "armhf".

One of these names is very different – "amd64" is the original name for x86_64, which is the 64-bit version of the usual Intel/AMD x86 CPU architecture found on typical PCs **and has nothing to do with ARM CPUs.** (The 32-bit version originates from Intel and is always called "x86" or sometimes "i386", "i686", but never "amd32". Only the 64-bit extensions were created by AMD.)

Your Raspberry Pi 4 has a 64-bit ARMv8 CPU, so "aarch64"/"arm64" is the most suitable architecture for it, although it's capable of running an 32-bit "armv7h" OS as well. (Similar to how 64-bit amd64 PCs can still run a 32-bit x86 OS.)

Comment: AArch32 is used by ARM to name the 32-bit ISA.